# WP can't send newsletters

Tags: plugins, email

I'm using ALO EasyMail Newsletter plugin in order to send newsletters to subscribers. I have setup settings which is mainly the email address and try to send an email for subscribers but it doesn't send anything. Is there any special configuration for wordpress to do?

Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote? Don't down vote unless you can comment why.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using http://mailchimp.com/

Comment: @Steven I downvoted the Q too. As you can read in the comments below (_if_ you read them), it's on a local machine. Not updating the Q with the info = downvote for a poorly asked Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a server config problem. Try looking for a custom SMTP plugin and set it up with that.

Comment: I don't think so I'm testing it on a local machine

Comment: Well then there is your problem probably. Local servers are basic. Will be flagging for moval to proper site

Comment: I agree with xLRDxREVENGEx that this will be a local config problem. By default local setups wont be able to mail out. If you are using something like XAMPP then you need to configure the PHP Mail settings first before you can mail out.

Answer (score 1):

Please not - I just realized - that if you set the "log file" option, then no emails will be sent, instead, they go in the log file. And not both (log file + sending). Sending will work as soon as you turn out the log file option under settings.